# wpf overriding getHashCode and Eqaul in ContentControl

Tags: wpf, linq, compare, hashcode, gethashcode

Hi
I have a class which derives from ContentControl and I'm not able to override GetHashCode and Equal method. I get an error

Error 5  cannot override inherited member 'System.Windows.DependencyObject.GetHashCode()' because it is sealed 
Is there any way to override this method ?
I need to use Union method from LINQ however I need to compare object with different condition than normal. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - implement [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) separately, and pass that into the [relevant overload of `Union`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407.aspx).

Basically you'll be telling it how to compare any two items for equality, and how to take the hash code of any one item. `Union` will use your custom comparison when building up hash sets etc. You don't need to override any existing methods.